# There is no SPICE protocol in vinagre for Ubuntu

Tags: vinagre

There is SPICE in vinagre for Fedora, but in the same version of vinagre in Ubuntu there is no SPICE. Why?

Answer (score 0):

SPICE wasn't available in Vinagre because it used to be compiled without support for it. Reading the [Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=726631) it appears that this choice was related to the fact that *libspice-client-gtk* is only available on i386 and amd64, and not on other architectures.

However, since [version 3.12](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vinagre/3.12.0-1), Vinagre is now built with the right build-dependencies and hence has SPICE support. You can find it in Utopic.